# parskip Causing amsbook Table of Contents Header to Appear Below Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, parskip, amsbook

I'm using the `amsbook` document class along with the `\parskip` package, but when `\parskip` is added, it causes the default header "Contents" above my table of contents to move below the table of contents itself. If `\parskip` is removed, the issue is resolved. I also tested this this with the `amsart` document class and the same thing is happening there. However, when using the document class `article` the issue does not occur. Can anyone shed some light on this?

I need to use the functionality of `\parskip` (in particular paragraphs that aren't indented) but I think I may need to find a different approach.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[english]{amsbook}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

\title{Title Here}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\part*{First Part}

\part*{Second Part}

\section*{First Section}

\section*{Second Section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! see if this helps: `\RequirePackage{parskip}
\documentclass[english]{amsbook}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

\title{Title Here}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\part*{First Part}
\part*{Second Part}
\section*{First Section}
\section*{Second Section}
\end{document}`.

Comment: This fixed the problem I described, but it eliminated the functionality of `\parskip` so the paragraphs are indented again.

EDIT: In fact, it appears to have the same effect as simply removing `\parskip` altogether.

Comment: What do you mean by “I need to use the functionality of `parskip` in particular paragraphs that aren't indented”? The `parskip` package is global. Can you please be more specific about your actual needs?

Comment: I need my paragraphs to not be indented and I want to control the space between paragraphs so I used the `\parskip` package. I want those aspects to be global. But using `\parskip` messes up the formatting of my table of contents for some reason. Take a look at the MWE I provided and you'll see what happens when `\parskip` is implemented with `amsbook`.

Comment: the `parskip` package redefines `\@starttoc` if that command has been redefined from what is in `latex.ltx`.  and `amsbook` *does* redefine `\@starttoc` since the desired style of the toc is *not* the same as for the basic latex classes.  (this might be expected of any non-basic document class.)  if all you want is unindented paragraphs and a larger `\parskip`, that should be possible with the following redefinitions: `\normalparindent=0pt \parindent=\normalparindent \parskip=0.5\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 0pt`.  (this may have an unexpected effect on lists.)

Comment: the `parskip` package is explicitly mentioned in the ams author handbook as being incompatible with `amsbook`.  (see the [handbook for monographs](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/tex/Author_Handbook_Mono.pdf), p.10.)

Comment: Ah, thank you for pointing me to that handbook, Barbara. In the end, I just dug through the `\parskip` package contents and extracted the macros I needed, in particular the three list `\def`'s there. Including those in my preamble (wrapped in `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`) solved my problem. Now the table of contents appears as it should and my paragraph formatting is correct.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because incompatibility of parskip with amsbook is stated in the handbook for authors.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I just dug through the `\parskip` package contents and extracted the macros I needed, in particular the three list `\def`'s there. Including those in my preamble (wrapped in `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` to accommodate the `@` symbols) solved my problem. Now the table of contents appears as it should and my paragraph formatting is correct.